# Inteference and energy conservation

Tags: electromagnetism, photons, solid-state-physics, maxwell-equations

I have this equation given in my lecture notes about interference between electromagnetic waves. I have searched the internet and cannot find it anywhere, I do not understand how you would come to this.
If anyone could tell my why or give a derivation that would be very useful.[image]

Answer (score 2):

You are adding two electric field of equal frequency $\omega$ whose phase differs by $\theta$ eg $E_1 \sin (\omega t)$ and $E_2 \sin (\omega t+ \theta)$.

A simple way of adding these two fields is to use a phasor diagram and the cosine rule.

[image]

The intensity is proportional to the square of the amplitude.

Comment: ok thank you that makes more sense, do you know where the cE0/2 comes into it?